Unable to login to SharePoint 2019 MySite
I prepared a lab SharePoint 2019 farm environment to test some migration issues. After creation of a web application, I am unable to login to the site, even with the domain admin credentials. I have performed the actions as listed below:

Created a DNS entry on domain controller for the URL mysite.domain.local pointing to the web server (SP2019.domain.local - 10.10.1.105).

Ping works fine and points to the correct IP.

I generated the CSR and downloaded the web server certificate from the CA server for the site mysite.domain.local.

I created a web application in the SP 2019 environment using the URL mysite.domain.local and bind the web application in IIS with the downloaded certificate. I used the options NTLM as the default authentication provider.

Created MySite Host site collection on the root path of the web application.

When I try to browse the root site, I keep getting the log-on dialog asking me to enter username and password. I even used the domain admin credentials but still I keep getting such error. Please help.


EDIT: When I add alternate access mapping for the web application as https://mysite.sp2019.domain.local (local server name), I am able to access the site.
